# Running complexity of munkres library in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, hungarian-algorithm

I have been trying to implement a 0(n^3) version of Hungarian algorithm. I came across the munkres library as they claim to have the running time of 0(n^3). By looking at their code I am not sure how do they measure 0(n^3) because it seems like 0(n^4).

```
def __step4(self):
    """
    Find a noncovered zero and prime it. If there is no starred zero
    in the row containing this primed zero, Go to Step 5. Otherwise,
    cover this row and uncover the column containing the starred
    zero. Continue in this manner until there are no uncovered zeros
    left. Save the smallest uncovered value and Go to Step 6.
    """
    step = 0
    done = False
    row = 0
    col = 0
    star_col = -1
    while not done:
        (row, col) = self.__find_a_zero(row, col)
        if row < 0:
            done = True
            step = 6
        else:
            self.marked[row][col] = 2
            star_col = self.__find_star_in_row(row)
            if star_col >= 0:
                col = star_col
                self.row_covered[row] = True
                self.col_covered[col] = False
            else:
                done = True
                self.Z0_r = row
                self.Z0_c = col
                step = 5

print("In Step 4")        
return step

def __find_a_zero(self, i0=0, j0=0):
    """Find the first uncovered element with value 0"""
    row = -1
    col = -1
    i = i0
    n = self.n
    done = False

    while not done:
        j = j0
        while True:
            if (self.C[i][j] == 0) and \
                    (not self.row_covered[i]) and \
                    (not self.col_covered[j]):
                row = i
                col = j
                done = True
            j = (j + 1) % n
            if j == j0:
                break
        i = (i + 1) % n
        if i == i0:
            done = True

    return (row, col)

def compute(self, cost_matrix):
    """
    Compute the indexes for the lowest-cost pairings between rows and
    columns in the database. Returns a list of (row, column) tuples
    that can be used to traverse the matrix.

    :Parameters:
        cost_matrix : list of lists
            The cost matrix. If this cost matrix is not square, it
            will be padded with zeros, via a call to ``pad_matrix()``.
            (This method does *not* modify the caller's matrix. It
            operates on a copy of the matrix.)

            **WARNING**: This code handles square and rectangular
            matrices. It does *not* handle irregular matrices.

    :rtype: list
    :return: A list of ``(row, column)`` tuples that describe the lowest
             cost path through the matrix

    """
    self.C = self.pad_matrix(cost_matrix)
    self.n = len(self.C)
    self.original_length = len(cost_matrix)
    self.original_width = len(cost_matrix[0])
    self.row_covered = [False for i in range(self.n)]
    self.col_covered = [False for i in range(self.n)]
    self.Z0_r = 0
    self.Z0_c = 0
    self.path = self.__make_matrix(self.n * 2, 0)
    self.marked = self.__make_matrix(self.n, 0)

    done = False
    step = 1

    steps = { 1 : self.__step1,
              2 : self.__step2,
              3 : self.__step3,
              4 : self.__step4,
              5 : self.__step5,
              6 : self.__step6 }

    while not done:
        try:
            func = steps[step]
            step = func()
        except KeyError:
            done = True

    # Look for the starred columns
    results = []
    for i in range(self.original_length):
        for j in range(self.original_width):
            if self.marked[i][j] == 1:
                results += [(i, j)]

    return results
```

These are the functions I was looking at and I think that for finding a zero function the complexity is 0(n^2) and since it is called in a while loop in step4 so it makes the complexity 0(n^3). Step 4 is called in a while loop in compute making the complexity 0(n^4). I want to know how they are claiming to have 0(n^3)?

Comment: Assuming the library you found is http://software.clapper.org/munkres/, they actually only claim that the Munkres algorithm is O(n^3), not that their implementation of it is.

Answer (score 0):

This library implements it in O(n^4). They have not claimed about their implementation to be O(n^3) but they just mentioned that Hungarian Algorithm is O(n^3).